# API xml response looping and extract all the element values - Groovy

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper

Below is the snapshot of my API XML response

```
<Plaintiff>
  <PlaintiffName>SEB B.A.
  </PlaintiffName>
  <PlaintiffName>SEB??
  </PlaintiffName>
</Plaintiff>
```

I want to extract all the PlaintiffName under the Plaintiff node.

Code:

```
String caseResponseText = response.getResponseText()
def xmlResult = new XmlSlurper().parseText(caseResponseText)
def plaintiff = xmlResult.Case.Plaintiff.PlaintiffName[0].text()
```

The above one i got the result of first plaintiff name / second plaintiff name. But how should i looping thru this node and get all the palintiff value dynamically?

Because response may have only one plaintiff or more than one, so I need to parse dynamically and get all the values thru looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop over the nodes:

```
def plaintiffs = xmlResult.Case.Plaintiff.PlaintiffName
for (plaintiff in plaintiffs) {
    // do something with plaintiff
}
```